# Researching the newest enties

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to check the newest entries and the size of it in the whole tablespace. Te used db is oracle 10g. 
I'm facing the problem, that the data is growing very fast. I need to monitor. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the below query will give you information about tablespaces

```
select * from user_tablespaces
```

or this one mentioned by devagree100

```
select * from dba_data_files
```

and try this I got it from this [site](https://community.oracle.com/thread/987315) hope it might help

```
select round((sum(bytes)/1048576/1024),2)
from V$datafile;

select round((sum(bytes)/1048576/1024),2)
from V$tempfile;
```

Take the sum of this two values which will be your total database size. Record this value daily/weekly/monthly basis and compare the difference.

and if you want the size of a table check the below:

```
SELECT owner,
segment_name,
segment_type,
tablespace_name,
bytes/1048576 MB,
initial_extent,
next_extent,
extents,
pct_increase
FROM
DBA_SEGMENTS
WHERE
OWNER = 'table owner' AND
SEGMENT_NAME = 'table name' AND
SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
```

Answer (score 2):

i would look in `dba_segments` to get a view on the size of each object

you can also look at the size of your data files using `dba_data_files`

Comment: Is there no way to find the most recent entries? Like : entries in table foo 5mb, sorted by size?

Comment: @user897237 you want the size of the tables ?

Comment: yes. i need to see how they are growing.if i had sizee of the  tables i would be able to make own statistics if there is nothing , which let me do it automatically.

Comment: dba_segment will give you the size of the tables, you could write a scheduled job to insert the size of each object into a monitoring table every 5 mins (for example). Then query the monitoring table to see which objects are growing over time.

you may also be able to use the table SYS.AUD$, you could query this for any of your tables and see how many INSERTS, UPDATES there have been. The audit action list in here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#g1432037